# Npm start fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cloudinary

here is my terminal :-

- Q:\clone\node-cloudinary-instagram\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202
         throw new Error(msg);

  - Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object
    Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (Q:\clone\node-cloudinary-instagram\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:202:15)
    at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (Q:\clone\node-cloudinary-instagram\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:482:19)
    at module.exports (Q:\clone\node-cloudinary-instagram\routes.js:4:9)
    at Object. (Q:\clone\node-cloudinary-instagram\server.js:19:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
  - npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  npm ERR! errno 1  npm ERR!
    scotch-cloudinary@1.0.0 start:    `node server.js`
  - npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at    the
    scotch-cloudinary@1.0.0 start script.  npm ERR! This is probably
    not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
    above.
  - npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
    C:\Users\Chetan
    Sharma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-03-21T00_16_50_000Z-debug.log

Here is my package.json file code

```js
{
  "name": "scotch-cloudinary",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Demo on how to use Cloudinary",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Cloudinary"
  ],
  "author": "Christian Nwamba",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cloudinary": "^1.13.2",
    "ejs": "^2.5.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code? `server.js:19:20`

Answer (score 0):

check here `Q:\clone\node-cloudinary-instagram\server.js:19:20` (line 20)

`Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] at Route.`

this is a hint ^^^